# SharePoint 2010 and ASP.Net 4.0 on same IIS

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, iis

Can the IIS version in Windows Server 2008 R2 host all the following:

SharePoint 2010;
ASP.Net 4.0;
Classic ASP applications;
VB6 compiled .dll web applications.

If so, can SharePoint 2010 be the Default Web application when accessing the server?

Thanks,
Aaron

Answer (score 1):

**Sharepoint 2010 requires the .Net 3.5 framework.**

I guess it's because a new SP version was being developed at the same time as the new .Net version, SP 2010 couldn't use .Net 4.0 yet.

Edit: [here's the explanation in the words of the SharePoint Product Manager](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010general/thread/4be4d224-0a38-4ed3-95c9-d2c6bd1248d7):

> Unfortunately the release timeframes
>   didn't work out to get SharePoint 2010
>   built on .NET Framework 4.0.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about VB6 compiled .dll web application, but the rest is no problem.

Classic ASP isn't installed by default, but it's just a feature to enable.

As SharePoint is running .Net 3.5 it needs to be in a seperate AppPool from your .Net 4.0 sites.

Which site is the default is just a matter of selecting which Web Site is serving port 80 without a host header.

Answer (score 0):

The separation; that needs to be explained here is the "application pool" term; a pool can use only one .net version so if they're in different application pools then everything is fine for IIS.

With the default web application is a relative object; if you mean through http://example.com then this means the port 80 is assigned to eg. Sharepoint on the application server.